digiKam : To CLEAR the manual sort "Manual & By Date"
So the "manual" sort in digiKam is not entirely intuitive.  It took a few tries before I figured out to drop the photo to be moved onto the thumbnail of the position for it to be moved to.  Great.  Got it.  But in one of my albums, things have gotten weird and the sorting is all out of whack.  All my other albums are sorting and behaving normally.
??? How can I clear the manual sort [the tags, markers, list in an ini file]?  Or even, where is the manual sort data stored?  I figure in the main database, which will make it difficult to repair, but maybe not.  If no responses here I may try creating a new folder (album) and copying the files over (fresh) to see if that works.
Any help is obviously appreciated.
running digiKam 8.4.0 on Windoze 11 (looking forward to my Linux future...when the time is right).

Looking at the Digikam Database file (Digikam4.db) which is a rather standard SQLite3-format database(*), the Images table as a manualOrder column which is set to NULL in my database (where I have never used the manual order):

So to reset the field you would either edit manually one by one, or issue a command such as:
update images set manualOrder=null where album={album ID number}

where {album ID number} is of course replace by a number. The Images table has an Album column so if you you know one photo in the album you can find the album ID.
If you don't use a where ... clause the whole table is updated and you lose the manual order in the other albums.
Since it is a SQLite DB you can make a copy of the Digikam4.db and if something goes wrong you can just erase the damaged file and restore the copy.
(*) There are several Sqlite DB browsers. I use the one on Linux, but you should be able to find one for Windows (IIRC there is even one which is a Firefox add-on)

Wow!  Perfectly answered my friend.  I will explore options for SQLite browsers and tweak the database to fix whatever has gone wrong.  I wonder if I'm the only one who has ever had this issue.  A teacher I once had, said: "you always ask the hard questions".  I answered: "I can find the answers for all the easy ones!"  Thank you so much!

If you think this answered your question then consider marking the answer accepted (check mark under the votes). This makes the question/answer more visible to others.

So, an update for anyone else that may go through this problem in the future.  I downloaded and used DB Browser for SQLite (DB4S) and simply copied the NULL value from any adjoining cell to all the cells in the affected albums.  Worked flawlessly.
I will add (for others, to save their time): Don't bother attempting to simply copy the items to a new album (different name) - they retain the sort order flags and therefore (sensibly) stay manually sorted.
If I get the ambition I may recommend a feature update for digiKam: "Reset album sort order" that would simply execute the SQL command noted above to reset the field to NULL for the current album.
